# Posting a SOAP request with php

Tags: php, soap

I'm at a slight loss, havent touched a soap script in forever and looking around stackoverflow and google just confuses the matter more. PHP.net examples seem outdated as well.

The SOAP Request is supposed to POST to a **non-WSDL** url.
https://some.soapurl.com/provided

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:cam="http://kamp.gw.com/kamp">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cam:setRolesUpdatedRequest> 
         <cam:orgCode>username</cam:orgCode>
         <cam:password>password</cam:password>
         <cam:emails>
            <cam:email>abc@dom.com</cam:email>
            <cam:email>def@dom.com</cam:email>
            <cam:email>ghi@dom.com</cam:email>
         </cam:emails>
         <cam:updateAllUsers>false</cam:updateAllUsers>
      </cam:setRolesUpdatedRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Just running this snippet returns a 200 OK header, which is good.

```
try {
      $client = new SoapClient("https://abc.kamp.group.com/axis/services/KampService/setRolesUpdated");
   }
catch(Exception $e)
   {
      $e->getMessage();
   }
```

The Response i'm looking to get is supposed to look like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:returnStatus xmlns:ns1="http://kamp.gw.com/kamp">
            <ns1:type>S</ns1:type>
            <ns1:desc>Successful</ns1:desc>
        </ns1:returnStatus>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

EDIT:

I attempted a curl version to post the xml string directly.

```
$post_string = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cam="http://kamp.gw.com/kamp">
                   <soapenv:Header/>
                   <soapenv:Body>
                      <cam:setRolesUpdatedRequest>
                         <cam:orgCode>username</cam:orgCode>
                         <cam:password>password</cam:password>
                         <cam:emails>
                            <cam:email>abc@dom.com</cam:email>
                            <cam:email>def@dom.com</cam:email>
                            <cam:email>ghi@dom.com</cam:email>
                         </cam:emails>
                         <cam:updateAllUsers>false</cam:updateAllUsers>
                      </cam:setRolesUpdatedRequest>
                   </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>';

$user = "username";
$password = "password";


$headers = array(             
    "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"", 
    "Accept: text/xml", 
    "Cache-Control: no-cache", 
    "Pragma: no-cache", 
    "SOAPAction: \"run\"", 
    "Content-length: ".strlen($xml),
); 

$soap_do = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            "https://abc.kamp.group.com/axis/services/KampService/setRolesUpdated" );   
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100000); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        100000); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true ); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $post_string); 
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $headers);  //array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($post_string) )
curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $password);

$result = curl_exec($soap_do);
$err = curl_error($soap_do);  

var_dump($result);
echo "<br /><br />";
var_dump($err);
```

But unfortunately the result is

```
bool(false)

string(74) "Failed connect to abc.kamp.group.com:443; Connection timed out"
```

And i'm not certain if that's my fault or the web service's fault. Even though i get connection timed out, the header returned is still 200 Ok.

Answer (score 0):

First check that the SOAP service url and access credentials are working. Use [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/) or a similar tool to make a request independent of your PHP SoapClient code.

Also check if there are any IP address restrictions in place when making calls and, if so, create / ask for an exception for the IP address you are making requests from.

If everything checks, use [php.net SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) examples to make simple calls and build your script logic.

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient('http://soap.amazon.com/schemas3/AmazonWebServices.wsdl');
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
?>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Forgot i was behind a proxy, once i pointed curl to the proxy server everything worked out just fine.